# Windows shows OOM even though there's a lot of free memory. Random reboots

Tags: windows, reboot, out-of-memory

Since some time my PC reboots without any entry in the Windows event log. I restored bios settings to default to exclude potential incorrect OC issues, the temperature monitor does not show any outstanding temperatures nor does the reboot occur during heavy load. I ran memtest+ but it found no errors whatsoever.

Today Windows popped out such a warning, showing that OS is nearly out of memory even though there's plenty memory available. I think it might be related to those recent issues. Should this warning (in such scenario) suggest memory corruption?
[image]

Comment: You are low on virtual memory allow Windows to manage the size of the page file.

Comment: Which Windows version is this?

Comment: Windows 7 "a comment is too short"